# ReactJS - Material UI - Box width inconsistent different between pages with the same amount of px

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm dealing with a silly issue here. I've got a fresh project in Reaction 17.0.2 and I've got two pages with the same layout: A Box with some TextFields. I've set the maxWidth of both boxes to be 700px, yet one is wider than the other? It's really bothering me, I've double checked everything, what can be the cause of this?

[image]

[image]

AddMenu

```
return (
    <Box
      flexDirection="column"
      justifyContent="center"
      sx={{ maxWidth: "700px", m: 5, bgcolor: "cyan" }}
    >
      <TextField
        type="text"
        id="name"
        required
        value={menu.name}
        onChange={handleMenuChange}
        label="Name"
        name="name"
        sx={{ width: "100%", height: "60px" }}
      />
      <TextField
        type="text"
        id="description"
        required
        value={menu.description}
        onChange={handleMenuChange}
        label="Description"
        name="description"
        sx={{ width: "100%", mt: 2, height: "60px" }}
      />
      <TextField
        required
        type="number"
        id="price"
        value={menu.price}
        onChange={handleMenuChange}
        label="Price"
        name="price"
        sx={{ width: "100%", mt: 2, height: "60px" }}
      />
      <Button
        variant="outlined"
        onClick={submitMenu}
        sx={{ width: "100%", mt: 2, height: "60px" }}
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Box>
  );
```

UpdateMenu

```
return (
    <Box
      flexDirection="column"
      justifyContent="center"
      sx={{ maxWidth: "700px", m: 5, bgcolor: "cyan" }}
    >
      <TextField
        required
        type="text"
        id="name"
        value={currentMenu.name}
        onChange={handleMenuChange}
        label="Name"
        name="name"
        sx={{ width: "100%", mt: 2, height: "60px" }}
      />
      <TextField
        required
        type="text"
        id="description"
        value={currentMenu.description}
        onChange={handleMenuChange}
        label="Description"
        name="description"
        sx={{ width: "100%", mt: 2, height: "60px" }}
      />
      <TextField
        required
        type="number"
        id="price"
        value={currentMenu.price}
        onChange={handleMenuChange}
        label="Price"
        name="price"
        sx={{ width: "100%", mt: 2, height: "60px" }}
      />
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
        }}
      >
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          onClick={updateMenu}
          sx={{ width: "100%", mt: 2, mr: 2, height: "60px" }}
        >
          Update
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="outlined"
          onClick={() => navigate("/")}
          sx={{ width: "100%", mt: 2, height: "60px" }}
        >
          Return
        </Button>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
```

App

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Box height="100vh">
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <MenuItem component={Link} to="/">
            <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
              Menu
            </Typography>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem component={Link} to="/add">
            <Typography textAlign="center">Add</Typography>
          </MenuItem>
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} />
          <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Box
        sx={{
          backgroundColor: "#EAECEE",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          height: "100%",
        }}
      >
        <Routes>
          <Route path={"/"} element={<MenuList />} />
          <Route path={"/menus"} element={<MenuList />} />
          <Route path={"/add/"} element={<AddMenu />} />
          <Route path={"/menu/:id/update/"} element={<UpdateMenu />} />
        </Routes>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Inspect

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've figured out that the difference is in the buttons. On one page there's a single button, the other one has a Box with two buttons. The latter is smaller, but I still don't understand why. If someone can explain that would be awesome.

Comment: You can set the `Box` wrapping the two buttons to have `width: 100%`.

Comment: @morganney Thanks but that didn't fix it unfortunately.

Comment: What do you see when you inspect the two in your browser dev tools? That should show you the width and computed width and who/where it was set. I note that box doesn't have a fixed width, only a max-width.

Comment: @AHaworth I see 630x1025 and 715x1025, I can't see a difference in CSS or div classes.